# Spring does rollback while saving at finally block of try-catch

Tags: spring, exception

This is the class to save:

```
@Service
public class DataService {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public String fetchData() { //no exception signature

    try {
      //some operations
      checkData();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      throw new CanerRuntimeException("an error occurred in fetchdata: " + e.getMessage(), e);//it cant come here with exception from child
    }

  }

  private void checkData() throws SystemException { //intellj made me put that exception

    try {

      //some operations

      if (!isCanerNotMade) {
        String errorMessage = "It is not caner made by";

        throw new CanerBusinessException(errorMessage);
      }

    }
  } catch(CanerBusinessException e) {
    logger.error("CheckForFksLimitations CanerBusinessExceptionerror {}", e.getMessage());
    throw e;
  }

} catch(Exception e) {
  logger.error("CheckForFksLimitations Exception error {}", e.getMessage());
  throw e;
} finally {
  if (fksLog != null) {
    saveLog(fksLog);
  }
  logger.info("CheckForFksLimitations ended for identityNumber: {}", identityNumber);//3
}

}

@Transactional
private void saveLog(FksLog fksLog) {

  try {
    logger.info("CheckForFksLimitations saving fksControlLog: {}", mobilityUtil.getObjectAsJson(fksControlLog));//1
    FksControlLog savedfksControlLog = fksControlLogRepository.saveAndFlush(fksControlLog);
    logger.info("CheckForFksLimitations saved fksControlLog: {}", mobilityUtil.getObjectAsJson(savedfksControlLog));//2
  } catch(CanerBusinessException e) {
    logger.info("CheckForFksLimitations error: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}

and that exceptions are:

public class CanerBusinessException extends RuntimeException {}

public class CanerRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {}
```

I send data for both cases. One for not to throw exception and it can save without any rollback. I made **saveAndFlush** because it cant save inside a readonly=False parent method. That is how it can save as child.

But when i send the case to throw exception, it throws exception. It goes to finally block then save method. But after that, it rolls back

I see those logs:

> CheckForFksLimitations saving fksControlLog: {"id":null,
> CheckForFksLimitations saved fksControlLog: {"id":91,
> CheckForFksLimitations ended for identityNumber: ARJUNA016129: Could not end XA resource com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a4@2a5410b8 com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.XaException: [jcc][t4][10401][12066][4.24.92] Xa exception: XA_RBROLLBACK ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null

It is oracle db.

I did not put any rollback class for exception. It is because of this?

I also put exception to parent signatures but did not work. This service called by a controller.

Comment: You can't get a new transaction within the same class, spring does its magic by proxying the class in question. When calling within the same class you avoid the proxy tha thandles the transaction. 

You need to exit the class and call back into the `savelog` method

Comment: But without exception, it is working?

Comment: An exception will trigger the rollback as its all part of the same transaction

Comment: It worked , thank you. So, i dont have to use saveandflıush(), i used it to save nder readonlyfalse paret.